# MS Access: VBA code is exporting the query, but not the latest results

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some code that exports a query, but when I looked at the export I noticed that it isn't actually running the query before exporting. It seems to be using the results of some previous run of the query or something.

**My VBA code:**

```
    Dim myQueryName As String
    Dim myExportFileName As String

    myQueryName = "qry_A" 
    myExportFileName = "J:\blah\Spreadsheet_" & Me![Combo353].Value & ".xlsx" 
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, myQueryName, myExportFileName, True
```

I have a feeling that somewhere in this code I need to run the query? But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the destination workbook file exists, delete that file before `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.

```vb
Dim myQueryName As String
Dim myExportFileName As String

myQueryName = "qry_A" 
myExportFileName = "J:\blah\Spreadsheet_" & Me![Combo353].Value & ".xlsx"
If Len(Dir(myExportFileName)) > 0 Then
    Kill myExportFileName
End If
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, myQueryName, myExportFileName, True
```

Comment: This worked. I knew this was always an option based on research, but I was really curious as to the specific reason why it wasn't working. It turns out that the results of the export were going into Sheet 2 of the file, which I never noticed. But I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Either you were suppressing an error message (like with `On Error Resume Next`) or the data was going into another sheet in an existing workbook.  I didn't know which, so it was quicker for me to give you something which was certain to work.  ;-)